# Action script with C# Console application

Tags: c#, php, actionscript-3, flash

**Warning:** I am asking for a good tutorial or a way to research how to do this not for you to code it for me

I am looking for a way that when a user does things in my swf game coded with Action Script 3.0 then it is handeld in c# in a void. So i want my game to send requests to call a function to my c# application.

I am brand new to Action Script but not C# I know alot of c# but i don't know how to go about doing this with the action sctipt, I have looked it up and found a tutorial [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb0.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c9f)

But it wasnt what i was looking for and I had a few errors when adding the code. I know this can be done because it has been done with a game someone else created, Some of you may know it its called Habbo its a very famous game and is coded like I want my game coded.

So to sum things up what i Want to do is Add some buttons and other things such as changing clothes and walking around in rooms in my action script game but i need a c# application to handle all this and get a database connection to select the chat rooms from the databae and other things like the users login

When the user enters my game it gets the authentication ticket witch is added to a param of the swf like on my game.php it embeds the swf file and adds this code for it to get the auth ticket.

```
var flashvars =
        {
            "user.auth_ticket" : "<?php echo $authticket; ?>"
        }
```

It created a random auth ticket every time the user enters the game then they get the account by getting the username from that ticket so like SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE auth_ticket = 'the auth ticket'

The user must login on my website so it can get the auth ticket every time the user enters the game. It created a random digit for security purposes

It embeds the game like this

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://127.0.0.1/game/game.swf", "client", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, null);
```

When someone enters the game it also writes a line on the console application saying "username has enetered the game" and adds them to the online list in the c# program and when they exit the game it removed them and writes "username has left the game"

Answer (score 0):

`ExternalInterface` is more for a desktop app where the swf is embedded. The C# app communicated with several swf files that displayed menus and content.

It seems like you want a web version of something similar. Some of what you have listed can simply be done by hitting a web service via `URLRequest`.

Depending on your application and need there are also `Socket` and `URLStream` classes.

Comment: I know I don't know much about c# but 'Socket' is what the other game 'Habbo' uses to register a Session and then it controls the session inside the program. Is there any more information you can give me on the Socket way of doing this?